# How to automate filling out knockout form

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, automation, google-chrome-devtools

Hello I currently have a site with the following section in my chrome dev tools

```
<div class="itemEditorField-inputsRelation">
   <input class="details-relativeInput-ageOnset js-relativeInput-ageOnset" type="number" data-bind="numeric: ageOnset, attr: { min: 0, max: 999, placeholder: 'Age' }" min="0" max="999" placeholder="Age"></input>
</div>
```

How do I simulate entering text into the knockoutJS input field? I have tried ...

```
e = $.Event('keydown');e.keyCode=50;$('input.details-relativeInput-ageOnset.js-relativeInput-ageOnset').trigger(e);
```

but all it returns is the object itself.  I do not have the code itself to plug anything into.  I just have Chrome and JQuery to use.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a normal `value` binding, the trick would be firing the `change` trigger for the input field. This might work for you, but it's hard to say, since you have a `numeric` binding, which is not a standard binding handler, but a custom one. Whatever event causes the bound variable to be updated is what you want to trigger.

A demo with a `value` binding is below.

```js
var vm = {
  ageOnset: ko.observable('')
};

vm.ageOnset.subscribe(function(newValue) {
  alert("New value:" + newValue);
});

ko.applyBindings(vm);

setTimeout(function () {
  $('input').val('12').change();
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="itemEditorField-inputsRelation">
  <input class="details-relativeInput-ageOnset js-relativeInput-ageOnset" type="number" data-bind="value: ageOnset, attr: { min: 0, max: 999, placeholder: 'Age' }" min="0" max="999" placeholder="Age" />
</div>
```